# Can we use underscore's "where" to filter collection by CID

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am simply wondering if we can only filter Backbone collections by attributes, but not by other properties such as CID

is this correct:

```
_.where(collection,{cid:'xyz'}) // filters by cid property?

_.where(collection,{attributes:{firstName:'foo'}}) // filters by attributes.firstName?
```

I hope someone can understand my confusion about how to use where to filter on nested properties.

Can someone please explain is if it is possible to filter by a top level property like CID or if Backbone collections are configured to just filter by attributes.

Answer (score 5):

Normally you'd use [`_.where`](http://underscorejs.org/#where) to search an array of objects for matching properties. So saying `_.where(collection, ...)` doesn't make a lot of sense, you'd want to search the collection's [`models`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-models) array:

```
var a = _.where(collection.models, { cid: 'xyz' })
```

That will do more or less the same thing as:

```
var a = [ ], i;
for(i = 0; i < collection.models.length; ++i)
    if(collection.models[i].cid === 'xyz')
        a.push(collection.models[i])
```

`_.where` doesn't know about the special structure of a Backbone collection so it doesn't know that it should be looking at `collection.models` or that there are `attributes` inside the models unless you tell it. Since `cid` is a *property* of models rather than an *attribute*, the above `_.where` works.

If you want to search the model *attributes* then you'd want to use the [Underscore methods that are mixed into collections](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) as they are adjusted to look at the collection's `models` or the special [`Collection#where`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where) that knows about the `attributes` object inside models. So if you wanted to look for a `firstName` attribute then you'd say:

```
collection.where({ firstName: 'foo' })
```

There's no support for searching nested objects out of the box. However, all the `where`s are just wrappers for [`_.filter`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) so you can write your own predicate function that does whatever you want:

```
collection.filter(function(model) {
    // Do whatever you want to model, return true if you like
    // it and false otherwise.
});
```

---

For the most part you should try to ignore the `Backbone.Collection#models` and `Backbone.Model#attributes` properties and use the various methods instead. There's usually a better way to deal with models and attributes that will be sure to take care of any internal bookkeeping.

Comment: one thing that's weird is that collection.filter(func) returns a plain array not a Backbone collection. Do you know why that would be? For example, I wanted to chain filter and each. So it would be like  collection.filter(func1).each(func2)...but alas it is not possible with Backbone/Underscore, because collection.filter just returns a plain array :(

Comment: I'd guess that arrays are returned because there's extra collection-baggage (such as events) with no obvious way to copy them but you'd have to ask the Backbone authors about that. However, there are lots of useful things in `Array.prototype` such as [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: Guyz lets discuss all backbone.js related questions here : chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84541/backbonejs-mvc lets build this chat room & get answers really quick from active developers